# Blazor ElementReference is null on dinamically created inputs

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-6.0

I'm trying to make a simple UI where i'm showing some rows of items, and on each of them there is a quantity input. Those rows can change constantly: the user can add or delete them and also manually focus on the quantity input to change it's value.

When the user read a barcode i currently add the new corresponding row (this work), however, i want to automatically focus on the quantity input (this does not work).

To achieve that behaviour i'm currently trying this:

```
@foreach (WAArticoloSend art in articoli) {
    ....
    <input @ref="@art.Ref" placeholder="Qtà" @bind="@art.Quantita" onfocus="this.select()" @onkeyup="@OnQtaKeyPress" class="form-control" />
}
```

where **@art.Ref** is of type **ElementReference**.

To programmatically focus on this input i use

```
await art.Ref.Value.FocusAsync();
```

whenever the user read a new barcode.

If i load the page with some rows already saved, i have each ElementReference properly valued, so every programmatic focus work like a charm.
But if i start to add new rows i can see that **@art.Ref** is always null, making me unable to do automatic focus.

How can i get a valid ElementReference whenever i add a new row?

Comment: Where are you calling the FocusAsync? After the render? The ref's do not get set until the html is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple page that demonstrates how to assign the focus as I think you want to.

I use a single `ElementReference` that I assign on each loop: the last one is the one assigned and will get focus.

I set focus in `OnAfterRenderAsync`.  This ensures that everything (including the new loop) has rendered.

Note I also assign a `@key` to each loop to help the render track instances.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

@foreach (var country in countries)
{
    <label class="form-label">@country.Uid</label>
    <input class="form-control mb-2" @bind=country.Name @ref=this.element @key=country.Uid />
    <div class="m-1 p-1 bg-light">Set Value: @country.Name</div>
}

<div class="m-2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=this.AddCountry>Add Country</button>
</div>

@code {
    private List<Country> countries = new();
    private ElementReference? element;

    private void AddCountry()
        => countries.Add(new Country());

    protected async override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (element is not null)
            await element.Value.FocusAsync();
    }

    public class Country
    {
        public Guid Uid { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
        public string? Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```